# Upload Excel file which row contains date time format but not show

Tags: asp.net, c#-3.0

I have an excel file with one column data in datetime format. When I upload my file datetime format does not match those and file could not be uploaded.

Comment: add some code to show your problem

Comment: I have excel file which columns are "ProductionDate" "EmployeeCode" "OT" "EOT" "Rate"          When I Upload the excel file if the date format is not currect, the row is not uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to format the Date column in your excel. Just select the whole column - > right click - > format cells - > Date -> choose appropriate format.

Comment: The column may be 50000 or above. It may be changed data replace of month. such as mm/dd/yy. when type may wrong like 14/12/2012. Why is possible.

Comment: Have you tried it? If you have the control on the database where you want to upload your excel data, you can also try changing the data columns type to varchar maybe, and keep your excel date in general or text format and upload.

Answer (score 0):

Has Hitesh mentioned you can check the Column and check if it is a DateColumn. Once confirmed we can check the next steps.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I have given condition Production Date Column If(ProductionDate !=DBNull.Value). When the Data format is wrong, the Data Row would not show. Replace (ProductionDate != Null) then show the bad format of data to Reject grid.